# How to make the performance of NSTextField consistent with NSAttributedString?

Tags: core-graphics, nsattributedstring, nstextfield

We have an NSView that uses quartz's related methods to draw pictures and text, and we can control scale and translate.

It is similar to a vector graphics software. After double clicking the text layer, you can input text and display it in real time.

Now we need to add a requirement. Double click the text in the fixed area to freely edit and reuse NSAttributedString to draw on NSView. Therefore, we use NSTextField as a sub view of NSView.

But we don't know how to make NSTextField behave like NSAttributedString, because we want it to overlap with the text on NSView.

The following enables us to generate the component configuration code and result diagram.

```
        /// setup
    func setup(){
        let rect = tree.convertToRectOnView(rect: node.drawCellRect)
        textField.setFrameSize(rect.size)
        textField.setFrameOrigin(rect.origin)
        textField.isEditable = true
        textField.isSelectable = true
        let newFont = self.font.withSize(self.font.pointSize * self.zoomScale)
        let ps = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        ps.minimumLineHeight = newFont.ascender + abs(newFont.descender) + abs(newFont.leading)
        ps.maximumLineHeight = newFont.ascender + abs(newFont.descender) + abs(newFont.leading)
        textField.font = newFont
        textField.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: "title", attributes: [.font: newFont, .paragraphStyle: ps])
    }
```

[image]